# Request processing threads vs custom threads for async processing vs web server performance

Tags: java, multithreading, http, servlets, webserver

**Question**: When I create a custom thread to handle incoming HTTP request in asynchronous way, am I actually harming the performance due to introduction of too many threads?

**More insight**: 
Lets say an incoming requests require some heavy database operation to be performed. Web server is heavy loaded and at any given moment 10 request processing threads are constantly busy processing requests. Server has 10 cores so lets assume 1 thread per core is running.

The requests are processed in a synchronous way, each request processing threads handles the job from arrival till completion. There is some wait on database required though.

Possible "improvement" would be to change the flow a bit, instead of request processing thread handling the whole request, additional thread is created to handle the heavy database operation and request processing threads is released early.

This raises concerns
- now much more than 10 threads on 10 cores are required. 
- context switching will degrade performance

What I mean by request processing thread: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1834/geeie/index.html

What I mean by custom thread:

```
void handleHttpMethod(){
  //request processing thread running here
  executorService.submit(new DBTask())
  //request processing thread exits here
}
```

I know this is a bit opened question but I am really interested in your feedback and comments.

[EDIT]
*Even more details:* 
 I'm running a web application deployed to Glassfish3 server which handles ~1000 requests/sec. Each request involves some DB operation (storing some data and no need to wait for result) which is heavy compared to other logic performed within the request. I'm trying to understand how going async may affect webserver performance, as request processing threads will now have to share the CPU with my custom threads created to handle DB operation.

Comment: It entirely depends on what you're doing.  However, the answer is to use a decent language (ie, not Java) and use non-blocking IO.

Comment: @Slaks Frequently, companies impose language/environment requirements on developers.  Surely we can try to aid him without simply requesting a different language.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: Not without more detail...

Comment: Are you on [Java EE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets013.htm)?

Comment: yes McDowell, its Java EE 7. To give you some more details I updated the question description.

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* below assumes that your DB runs on different host, so DB queries won't take CPU from your web-serving threads.

If DB queries times vary by client you can definitely improve throughput (in terms of number of served requests) by offloading DB requests to "custom" threads.

E.g., if client1Query runs for 10 seconds and there are no free threads, client2Query, which would need only 1 second to complete, will need to wait till either client1Query finishes, or some other thread becomes available.

Comment: Thanks Victor, but DB operation blocks the thread which has to wait for its completion even though the DB server runs on different host.

Comment: @Mark sorry if my answer isn't very clear, but I meant exactly that -- offloading DB query to "custom" thread (most simply, by doing `executor.submit(new DBTask())`, which will free web-serving thread for next request immediately. You'll need to pick DB response asynchronously later on (e.g., via some `BlockingQueue`).

Comment: So you suggest to create a custom thread pool and submit db tasks to threads within this thread pool. And the impact of this design on a web server performance is exactly what I'm trying to discuss here. And you are saying it is definitely beneficial, thanks for your input Victor, lets see if there is any more feedback coming.

Comment: It's useful, because it frees threads for new tasks which are almost always will end fast (serving web resource for a next HTTP request), while having long-running tasks in background